# How to add Reusable Headers for swagger documentation using swaggerjsdoc and swaggeruiexpress

Tags: node.js, swagger, documentation, swagger-jsdocs, swagger-ui-express

Reusable Headers for swagger documentation using swaggerjsdoc.

Hi, I need to document my apis written in node js and I am using swaggerjsdoc and swagger express ui. I have about 11 different headers like deviceID, location etc and they will be used in 40,50 different requests, so instead of duplicating them in different request I want to use components section for reusability and want to use $ref for once so that it can get all the headers from components section. although it works but it returns one header object where I can put values Instead I want swaggerUi to show different string values for headers like shown in figure[image]

[image]

Below is my code snippet

```
/**
* @swagger
* components:
*   parameters:
*     headersArray:
*       in: header
*       name: headers
*       description: Array of headers
*       required: true
*       schema:
*         type: object
*         properties:
*           ipaddress:
*             type: string
*             description: Client IP Address
*             example: 192.168.0.1
*           location:
*             type: string
*             description: User location
*             example: New York
 */

/**
 * @swagger
 *  tags:
 *    name: Posts
 *    description: posts of users
 */

/**
* @swagger
* paths:
*   /your-endpoint:
*     post:
*       summary: Example POST endpoint
*       description: Example endpoint that requires headers
*       requestBody:
*         required: true
*         content:
*           application/json:
*             schema:
*               type: object
*               properties:
*                 exampleProperty:
*                   type: string
*       responses:
*         '200':
*           description: Success response
*       parameters:
*         - $ref: '#/components/parameters/headersArray'
 */
```